# How to get a fixed number of vertices after decimation in VTK

Tags: image, 3d, mesh, vtk, itk

I am working with VTK for 3D mesh processing. I have a mesh and I am using the function `vtkDecimatePro()` to get the reduction done. The function itself accepts a `TargetReduction`, that is related to the reduction in the number of triangles (percentage). The problem is that I need to have a fixed number of vertices, say for example I want all my meshes to have 2000 vertices. Currently I am doing this in a software called openflipper which allows to constrain the decimation to a fixed number of vertices. However, in VTK I am not sure how to accomplish this task.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set the desired number of vertices. It doesn't work that way. Even the target reduction is just approximate, and you are not guaranteed to get *exactly* the number of vertices.

What you could do, is very simply calculate the reduction factor and set that:

```
// desiredN is the desired number of vertices after reduction
double f = static_cast<double>(desiredN) / poly->GetNumberOfVertices(); 

//...
decimate->SetTargetReduction(1.0 - f);

// We want to preserve topology so that reduction factor applies to vertices 
// (otherwise it prescribes reduction in number of faces)
decimate->SetPreserveTopology(1);
```

HTH,

Miro

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mirni, but I think the function _SetTargerReduction_ is the reduction factor in the number of triangles (Not Vertices). I have used it in that way, and the reduction in terms of number of triangles is fine; however I have not been able to fix a reduction in number of vertices. I am wondering how is this done in OpenFlipper since there you can define the desired number of vertices, and so far it always produces a mesh with that number of vertices.

Comment: Roger, number of vertices and faces are tied through Euler formula to form a topological invariant, so if you force preserving topology, the number of verts and number of faces should vary both by the same amount, if your meshes are reasonably nice, i.e. manifolds with a small number of holes/handles in comparison to number of verts.
In practice this means you want to `SetPreserveTopology(1)` on the decimate filter to keep n verts and n faces vary consistently.

Comment: Thanks, doing tests now